# How to switch between soft keyboards on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am working on devices that I built some apps for. One of the apps requires no keyboard, but when a cursor focuses on an input (for scanning purposes) field, the softkeyboard shows up, but has no purpose so I decided to download this "Null Keyboard" [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wparam.nullkeyboard&hl=en_US)

When I go out of the app, the entire device is still using the Null keyboard.

Does anyone know how I could switch back to the default keyboard in Java on Android studio?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can return to default keyboard through System settings -> Language and Input -> Keyboards -> Soft keyboards. Or just using search in system settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to do it on the device. I need to find a way to do this programmatically. In Java.

Comment: I think @leenbean16 is looking for a programmatic way to do it, not via the UI.

Comment: Ok. Try `InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();` for show chooser of keyboards.

Comment: But you can't set some keyboard as default programmatically. Only through system chooser.

Comment: @АртемКомар that didn't work... I didn't get a keyboard picker. I will see if I can set a default keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get, set, and store something, any given thing, you can "put it back when you're done".

With android and keyboards in particular, I suspect you'd need to get the current keyboard when your app gains focus and save it, then set the null keyboard.

When the app loses focus, you need to set the original keyboard back again.

You'll need to do this every time you gain and lose focus, not just when your app starts and stops.

(Note that I haven't touched android development in something like 10 years, and I was never terribly experienced then either)

Comment: Hmm... Android has very set ways of doing things. I'm not sure if your method would work, but I appreciate the help!